# кнопку построение маршрут

Tags: android, yandexmapkit, mapkit

Я использую mapkit-android-demo. SearchActivity, DrivingActivity, вот кнопка:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              searchEdit.setText((CharSequence) ROUTE_START_LOCATION);`
            queryEdit.setText((CharSequence) ROUTE_END_LOCATION);
            }
        });
```

Не работает почему?

Comment: Что именно не работает, какая вообще задумка? Вам бы подробно ситуацию описать и с примером кода в поддержку Яндекса обратиться.

Comment: когда нажимаешь кнопку построить маршрут ,кнопка сбрасывает .а должна построить линия точка А в Точку Б